# Is the integral $\int \frac{\left (\sin(x) + \tan(x) \right ) \sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1} + \cos(x)} dx$ elementary?

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-writing

I've stumbled on the integral $\int \frac{\left (\sin(x) + \tan(x) \right ) \sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1} + \cos(x)} dx$ recently. I've been thinking how could I even try to integrate this thing, but I have absolutely no idea how could I do that. Then I thought that it may be non-elementary, but methods for proving that involve differential galois theory and some higher algebra I don't know. Are there any other ways for proving integral being non-elementary? If not, where could I learn that differential galois theory method? And if it's elementary, what is the antiderivative?

Comment: Group theory? Do you mean differential galois theory?

Comment: @JonasHardt yes, thank you. I've edited it and now it's differential galois theory

Comment: [This](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Murphy.pdf) is, in my opinion, a nice exposition to dgt if you already know basic ring and field theory... in case you don't, I would recommend you read a basic algebra book first (I recommend artin).